# imgur API v3 upload image keep getting back status 1203: "Imgur is over capacity. Please try again."

Tags: api, imgur, capacity

This is the request I am posting

```
POST /3/image HTTP/1.1
Host: api.imgur.com
Authorization: Client-ID <My client ID>
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"

http://png1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/home.png
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

However, the response I get is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "error": "Imgur is over capacity. Please try again.",
        "request": "/3/image",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    "success": false,
    "status": 1203
}
```

I just want to use anonymous upload but the documentation is saying limit of 10MB right? anything I have done wrongly? what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Imgur is over capacity; why do you think it's you?

Comment: but I just changed to json request and I get back error 400 with error message like ""error": "Image format not supported, or image is corrupt.""

Comment: okay. after many unsuccessful attempt, the response is okay now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imgur is frequently over capacity, so perhaps you can try again later. I doubt it's a problem on your end.

Comment: I would - sometimes when trying to access the site this error is displayed but it usually doesn't take too long to resolve itself if you keep refreshing or leave it alone for a few minutes.